# Is there a method using sympy import in python to differentiate an equation, and find only the real horizontal and vertical tangents of the equation

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am using sympy in python in order to implicit differentiate(x^3+y^3=12*x*y). The problem comes when I try to solve for the horizontal tangent lines and vertical tangent lines. I keep getting imaginary solutions for both.

This is my code so far

```py
from sympy import *

x,y,t=symbols('x y t')
LHS=x**3+y**3
RHS=12*x*y

dydx = idiff(LHS-RHS, y, x)
print(f'dy/dx = {dydx}')
print()

htan=solve([4*y-x**2,LHS-RHS],[x,y])
print('Horizontal tangents at',htan)
print()

vtan=solve([-x**2 + 4*y,RHS-LHS],[x,y])
print('Vertical tangents at',vtan)
print()
```

Whenever I try to print `htan` and `vtan` I keep getting imaginary solutions with the real solutions. Does anyone have an idea as to what I can do in order to only get the real horizontal and tangent lines?

Comment: aren't you supposed to add `real=True` in the solve function ?

Comment: I'm not sure where to add real = True in the solve function and I tried a few different places and they all gave me errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Archille mentioned in the comment, just set `real=True` when creating symbols, like this:

```py
from sympy import *

x,y,t=symbols('x y t', real=True)
LHS=x**3+y**3
RHS=12*x*y

dydx = idiff(LHS-RHS, y, x)
print(f'dy/dx = {dydx}')
print()

htan=solve([4*y-x**2,LHS-RHS],[x,y])
print('Horizontal tangents at',htan)
print()

vtan=solve([4*x - y**2,LHS - RHS],[x,y])
print('Vertical tangents at',vtan)
print()
```

**EDIT** to include improvements suggested by @smichr:

We can also visualize the results with [SymPy Plotting Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
from spb import *
xx1 = [p[0] for p in vtan]
yy1 = [p[1] for p in vtan]
xx2 = [p[0] for p in htan]
yy2 = [p[1] for p in htan]
graphics(
    implicit_2d(Eq(LHS, RHS), (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10), n=200),
    implicit_2d(dydx, (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10), label="dy/dx", n=500, adaptive=False),
    list_2d(xx1, yy1, label="vtan", scatter=True, rendering_kw={"marker": "x", "markersize": 10}),
    list_2d(xx2, yy2, label="htan", scatter=True),
    grid=False
)
```

[image]

If you look closely, the part of `dy/dx` that lies on the rightmost part of the chart appears to be "segmented". That's because there is an asymptote in its proximity and the surface is very very steep in that location. We can see it with a 3D plot:

```py
plot3d(
    dydx, (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10),
    wireframe=True, backend=PB, n=500, zlim=(-10, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: I love you bro thx

Comment: This gives the same solution for both cases. I suggest editing the `vtan` to read `solve([4*x - y**2,LHS - RHS],[x,y])`. @Davide_sd, I was hoping for an implicit plot showing the intersections! :-)

Comment: Thanks @smichr, it didn't even crossed my mind :) Done it.

Comment: The 2D graph helps visualize it quite a bit thanks, but I ain't gon lie I have no idea what's going on in the 3D plot but it looks cool so thanks.

Comment: Basically, when you do an implicit 2D plot you are visualizing the zero-contour of a 3D plot. Take a look at the 3D plot: the intersection between f(x, y) and the plane z=0 gives the 2D implicit plot. Now, the 3D plot shows that f(x, y) goes to infinity (the asymptotes). Sadly, the plotting module is not good at analyzing asymptotes in 3D plots, so you get some weird artifacts....